# How can I soften the clicking sound of a light switch

Tags: lighting, switch, sounds

I am renovating my house. The contractor has rewired my house and installed rocker switches for my lighting. The big button looks good. But flipping the switch produces a loud snapping sound. Short of replacing those switches, is there a way to soften the audible click whenever I flip the wall switch?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Would you be willing to put some muffling material over each switch? If not, then probably your only solution is to replace the switch. (There used to be silent, mercury-based toggle switches, but I doubt they're for sale anymore due to having a built-in toxic waste site.)

Comment: snapping light switches are the safest, most durable switch out there. the snap is caused by the mechanism quickly breaking/connecting the electrical circuit. this fast action prevents arcing which erodes the metal parts inside and can cause a fire. modern switches often dont have this snapping action which is why they dont last very long.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.  Your option is pretty much replace the switch with a quieter one.  Switches are $2 to $5.

Since SE archives questions, I'll mention that some switches are loud because they are special switches rated to switch high current - in that case, don't downgrade.

Answer (score -2):

Is it mounted on wood or plywood surface?

The loud snapping sound probably due to the the vibration amplification by the surface on which the rocker switch is mounted on.

The very first thing you could do is try install a layer of felt or similar soft material between the contact surfaces of the switch and the wall on which its mounted on.

This should reduce the sound significantly.  If its still loud for you, go one step further to disassemble the switch and stuff the moving nonconductive parts with damping grease.

https://www.rocol.com/products/kilopoise-high-viscosity-damping-grease

Here you can find about the grease I am talking about.

Comment: Are you familiar with standard wiring practice in the US and Europe? You won't find light switches mounted directly to walls.